# Get SID of current user as std::string. c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sid

Get SID of current user as string. c++

I've been thinking how to get sid in c# it's easy like this: `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value;`

If someone can give me short solution to get SID as std::string i will be happy.

Comment: Call GetTokenInformation with TokenUser, then use ConvertSidToStringSid to convert it from binary format to string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these WINAPI functions:

- ConvertStringSidToSid(), to convert the account SID strings to a SID that is required as an argument to,
- LookupAccountSid()